# Computer Algebra/Symbolic Computing: Algorithm to determine if real function is nondecreasing

Tags: algorithms, real-numbers, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

Suppose I have a differentiable function $f:[a, b]\rightarrow R$, with $a,b\in I\!R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, with $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}=1$. Is there any algorithm to determine if $f$ is nondecreasing?

What about particular cases of the problem (Rationals, Integers, limited or finite image - finite domain is trivial, any other nontrivial set)?

Comment: With no restriction on $f$ and a domain with infinitely many elements how could there be an algorithm that didn't have to look at the value at every point of the domain at least once?

Comment: How can we compute limits without explicit expressions for epsilon? Gruntz algorithm and many others do.

Comment: A limit argument can only work with some assumption on $f$. The question suggests that it   $f(x)$ might be essentially random. If you provide information about how $f$ is defined (as algorithm input) then there might be an answer to the question.

Comment: Nervermind. I will test if the first derivative is nonnegative.

Comment: Oh. So you know $f$ is differentiable ...

Comment: Added three assumptions about $f$ and it's domain. and generalized the domain a bit more. I'd still like to see a somewhat more structured answer.

Comment: Checking the nonnegativity of the derivative *is* the algorithm. I have a gut feeling, although not a proof, that it is provably the *only* algorithm.

Comment: I would love to see a sketch of proof   :)

Comment: @CarlLove or just a sketch of your reasoning

Comment: Basically, the problem is intractable if there are infinitely many points of nondifferentiability.